# Android Room - Handling List of Objects in an Object and querying result

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-room

Im working with Android's Room Database and am having some big problems understanding how to:

1. When I add a `Person` to the database, it adds all its variables e.g. `List<Shoe>`,`List<Pet>` etc. to the database as well.
2. Create relations such that when I retrieve a `Person`, all its fields are retrieved e.g `Pet, Shoe, Shirt` etc. (Not sure what type of query that is)
3. Perform simple query e.g. `Retrieve Person where`shoe.name`= "boot"`;

I know you must use Foreign Key relationships with list of objects, otherwise with a single object one can use `@Embed` or `@TypeConverter`

Sample code is shown below;

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
    public class Person {
        @PrimaryKey
        @NonNull
        private String personId;
        private List<Pet> pets;
        private List<Shoe> shoes;
        private List<Shirt> shirts;
    }

@Entity(foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
                entity = Person.class,
                parentColumns = "personId",
                childColumns = "personIdFk"
        )
    })
    public class Pet {
        String petId;
        String name;
        String personIdFk; //Foreign key to person
    }

@Entity(foreignKeys = {
            @ForeignKey(
                    entity = Person.class,
                    parentColumns = "personId",
                    childColumns = "personIdFk"
            )
    })
    public class Shoe {
        String shoeId;
        String name;
        String personIdFk; //Foreign key to person
    }


@Entity(foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
                entity = Person.class,
                parentColumns = "personId",
                childColumns = "personIdFk"
        )
    })
    public class Shirt {
            String shirtId;
            String name;
            String personIdFk; //Foreign key to person
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Room doesn't support this directly due to some [potential issues with lazy loading](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data.html#understand-no-object-references), but with some DAO trickery it is possible. You'll need to handle the insertions explicitly, and to query everything at once you'll need a POJO to wrap it all.

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = {
    @ForeignKey(
            entity = PersonEntity.class,
            parentColumns = "personId",
            childColumns = "personIdFk",
            onDelete = CASCADE
    )
})
public class Pet {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String petId;
    private String name;
    private String personIdFk;
}

@Entity(tableName = "person")
public class PersonEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String personId;
}

public class Person {
    @Embedded
    private PersonEntity personEntity;
    @Relation(parentColumn = "personId", entityColumn = "personIdFk")
    private List<Pet> pets;
}

@Dao
public abstract class PersonDao {

    @Insert
    protected abstract void insert(PersonEntity personEntity);

    @Insert
    protected abstract void insert(List<Pet> pets);

    @Transaction
    public void insert(Person person) {
        insert(person.getEntity());
        insert(person.getPets());
    }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    public abstract List<Person> getAll();

}

@Database(entities = {PersonEntity.class, Pet.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract PersonDao personDao();

}
```

Constructors, getters and setters omitted for brevity.